# NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification not firing when it should… or at all?

Tags: cocoa, nsuserdefaults, nsnotifications

In my application, I have registered the NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification notification in awakeFromNib along with my other notifications (which are working fine). I register it just as shown below, which appears to be correct:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myAction:) name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}
```

and my action method appears to be correctly formatted as well:

```
- (void)myAction:(NSNotifcation*)notifcation
{
    NSLog(@"foo);
}
```

For unknown reasons, however, it refuses to fire at all. No matter how many of the application's defaults are changed, it never fires even once. Am I registering wrong or is something else the cause? Has anybody else experienced this problem in the past?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` instead of the workspace notification center?

Comment: No I haven't, but I will now. Do some notifications require it over the shared workspace notification center?

Comment: Most notifications are sent to the default notification center. The shared workspace notification center is meant for system-wide things like mounted volumes, timezone changes etc.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'm going to end up not using notifications for this particular feature, but that's a good thing to know anyway.